Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 4.1 sound system plays only front speakers
I have usb sound card that allows 4.1 sound system.
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HJ070NA]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ICUSBAUDIO7D [ICUSBAUDIO7D], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

In ubuntu settings I set the 4.1 system
setting
and when I test individual speaker using test button, each speaker works, and I can hear voice telling which speaker is active.
But the problem is that when playing sound via VLC or web browser only front speakers plays and others stays silent.
in VLC I have default pipewire as sound device (sound server) but trying any other setting does not work with 4.1 sound system (onlt front speakers are playing)
I tried adding some pipewire settings, installing hdajackretask, trying configuring pulseaudio without success. Now I am stuck.
here is output of pactl list for that sound card.
Card #47
    Name: alsa_card.usb-0d8c_USB_Sound_Device-00
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "ICUSBAUDIO7D at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4.3, full speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "ICUSBAUDIO7D"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-0d8c_USB_Sound_Device-00"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.4.3:1.0"
        device.description = "CM106 Like Sound Device"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-0d8c_USB_Sound_Device-00"
        device.nick = "ICUSBAUDIO7D"
        device.plugged.usec = "5872753"
        device.product.id = "0x0102"
        device.product.name = "CM106 Like Sound Device"
        device.serial = "0d8c_USB_Sound_Device"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4.3/1-3.4.3:1.0/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "35"
        object.id = "47"
        object.serial = "47"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "ICUSBAUDIO7D"
        alsa.long_card_name = "ICUSBAUDIO7D at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4.3, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB0d8c:0102"
        alsa.id = "ICUSBAUDIO7D"
        device.string = "1"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5555, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 55, available: yes)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "mic"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-linein: Line In (type: Line, priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "line"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "spdif"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "speaker"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                card.profile.port = "3"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "spdif"
                card.profile.port = "4"
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo

Edit: while trying to fix sound issue I installed a Helvum and discover this:
enter image description here
I am not sure if libcanberra should be connected to my soundcard that many times. (in image all inputs to CM106 sound card comes from different instances of libcanberra). I also encounder a noticable delay for VLC to change volume, along with freezes for ubuntu system sound setup and not working sound from web browser when vlc is active)

I kinda solve my problem by installing helvum
sudo apt install helvum
and configuring it like that:
enter image description here
but I need to do this every time I run VLC or web browser.
I tried to be "smart" and wire an monitor_FL/monitor_FR to playback_RL/playback_RR but this works only partially. Sometimes it blocks playback at all, and this wires must be disconnected.
